# Link to iTunes  have to restart app

Tags: objective-c, ios, itunes

Im Linking to appstore from my app using

```
`NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/companyname/";
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

This works,  but when returning to my app it's just a blank screen and I have to restart the app.

Am I missing some fundemanatal piece of code here

Comment: what happens in your applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground, etc ?

Comment: Oh...nothing? I take I need to be doing something here? When I link out to webpages facebook etc, this isnt an issue, only when going to the Appstore

Comment: This isn't a problem with your iTunes link code, you'll have to look elsewhere for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a link with this format itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789

Comment: Did you change the ap ID at the end?

Comment: Surley did, loads up the appstore but gives me an error and still gives me the same problem with a blank screen when i return to my app